# Can I use LaravelCollective/html for a Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravelcollective

I used the [laravelcollective/html](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) package in my Laravel 5 Blade/Bootstrap applications, and now I see that there is no support for Laravel 8. Can you advise something similar compatible with Laravel 8 or this library, OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use this package with Laravel 8. Just add the package as you normally would with Composer.

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Just make sure, in this case, that in composer.json, it is using version 6.2. Here is [confirmation](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/releases/tag/v6.2.0) that Laravel 8 is supported.